# Django Serializer nested relation where 2 models are not directly related?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to get nested results for cases where 2 models are not directly related but indirectly related through a table.

below is just to replicate the situation i am in and not the actual code that i am using.

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Artist
       fields = ['name', 'age']

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration', 'artist']

class ConcertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer(read_only=True)
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Concert
        fields = ['concert_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

`Artist` and `Track` are related. Also, `Artist` and `Concert` are related. But I want to get `tracks` using `TrackSerializer` to get tracks with same artist for a concert when they are not directly related. Is this possible? There will be multiple tracks for a concert.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of ways of achieving that, considering you have one artist per concert, you could try using a `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class NestedTrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration',]


class ConcertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer(read_only=True)
    tracks = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tracks(self, instance):
        return NestedTrackSerializer(instance.artist.tracks.all(), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Concert
        fields = ['concert_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```